# Iterating Sequentially on the URL when running a Python API

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to pull data from an API for a fantasy football project I'm working on. You can pull data on various players using the url: 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/i/' where i is a number that relates to a player and runs from 1 to 400 or so.

I wrote code that pulls this data for a specific player and stores it as a dataframe for future analysis using the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

r = requests.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/1/')
r_json = r.json()
r_df = pd.DataFrame(r_json['history'])
r_df.head()
```

And this works great. The issue is it's only for 1 player and there are lots of them, so what I want is a DataFrame that contains this data for all of the players. I figured I could use a for loop for this but I can't get it to work. I'm trying the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


for i in range(5):
    r = requests.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/{}/'.format(i))
    r_json = r.json()
    r_df= pd.DataFrame(r_json['history'])
    r_df.head()
```

Where I've put the logic in a for loop, but I get the error:

KeyError: 'history'

When I try to run this. Why does it not like the line r_df= pd.DataFrame(r_json['history']) when it's in a for loop when it's OK outside of one?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your loop is trying to query `'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/0/'` on the first iteration, which doesn't exist. (Or, rather, gives you the JSON `{"detail": "Not found."}`, which doesn't have a `"history"` key.)

The built-in `range` function generates integers starting from zero by default. Try changing the loop range to `range(1, 5)` instead. (Also note that the end of the range is exclusive, so this will give you integers from 1 to 4.)

Answer (score 0):

A KeyError indicates that the dictionary does not have this specific key.

Your specific problem here is that the `range()` function is generating the following range: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] because if you don't specify an initial value, it will take 0 as an initial value and stop at one short of the final value.

And so *https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/0/* doesn't return anything.

To fix this change `range(5)` to `range(1, 6)`.

Note: the syntax of the `range()` function is: `range(starting_point, ending_point, step)`